# After random import the simulation is always breaking down

Tags: python, random, import, python-import, vpython

I want to generate a random number and use it later. It also works, the simulation loads like for 0.5 sec and then I see it. But then the simulation breaks down and the simulation window quits. I also can't use e.g. `import random` it happens the same thing. Could it be that the random package doesn't work with Vpython?

```
Syntax error File "/Users/colinm/Desktop/random.py", line 2 import random from randint ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax –
```

Code

```
from vpython import*
import random from randint



#Sonne
sun = sphere(pos = vec(0,0,0), radius = 9, make_trail = True ) 
sun.mass = 2e30   
sun.velocity = vec(0,0,0)

#Merkur
mercury_pos_x = randint(1, 100)
mercury = sphere(pos = vec(mercury_pos_x,0,0), radius = 5, color=color.red, make_trail = True ) 
mercury.mass = 3.25e23
mercury.velocity = vec(0,0,-47000)

#Venus
venus_pos_x = randint(1, 100)
venus = sphere(pos = vec(venus_pos_x,0,0), radius = 6, color=color.cyan, make_trail = True ) 
venus.mass = 4.9e24
venus.velocity = vec(0,0,-35000)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem you're having is from your description. Your code above runs fine except for your import statement which has the order of import and from wrong and should be:

    "from random import randint"

All you are doing in the code above is specifying the parameters. It sounds like your code is simply finishing, which is why the window would be closing.

Comment: Now e I even get a syntax error. I added it in the question. Its so strange sometimes it happens the the first problem(quitting) and sometime it say syntax error

Comment: As I suggested above, that error is caused by the import statement. Change "import random from randint" to "from random import randint".